# params with fb js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey guys am new to javascript facebook sdk .When i learn about the params in javascript i feel so confused.My code is

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
alert('Error occured');
  } else {
alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

This code works well ..But my doubt is that can we use the code like

```
    var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
    FB.api('/me/feed?message=body', 'post',  function(response) {
 if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
      } else {
alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
      }
    });
```

Is there any problem with the second type of code ..Can it be done in Fb js sdk ..

Hope you guys can help me ..Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works.. But Let me explain this a bit.

FB.api() method is declared as follows

> FB.api(path, method, params, callback)

The `method` parameter given here is "post" which is equivalent to an html post. 
As per the api documentation posting something to feed should be done with post method.
For a post method, to be on the safe side pass parameters through `params`

Lastly some javascript syntax. Here `body` is a variable so it should be `FB.api('/me/feed?message='+body,...` or the text `body` will be posted to your feed

Try out your code in the [Test Console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/)
See [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api) for more details